# The best way to store filter conditions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relational-database

See the following sample data:

```
[{
    customerGroup: "Group 1",
    field: "gender",
    filter: {
        eq: "female"
    }
}, {
    customerGroup: "Group 1",
    field: "age",
    filter: {
        between: {
            from: 18,
            to: 25
        }
    }
}, {
    customerGroup: "Group 1",
    field: "contry",
    filter: {
        includes: ["US", "GB", "FR"]
    }
}]
```

What is the best table structure to store this data in PostgreSQL?

Comment: A single table with three columns: `customer_group`, `field` and `filter_condition`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the answer! But what about data type of the `filter_condition` column? Should we store more than one value in one column ?

Comment: @Mike you can use [JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-json.html) for `filter_condition`